# SQL: Display book information for books that are above average retail price

Tags: sql, database, oracle

No to sure how to display book information for only books that are above the average retail price. Any input will help, thanks.

Comment: From tables books (isbn,title,retail), bookauthor(isbn, authorid), author(last,first,authorid)

Answer (score 0):

You could join a query from the table with a query to get the average price:

```
SELECT title
FROM   books b
JOIN   (SELECT AVG(retail) AS avg_price
        FROM   books) a ON b.retail > a.avg_price
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this is homework. So try to understand the clauses you are using. You can use the `GroupBy` with the `Having`. You need to take a look at the having clause.[Here is more info on the clause](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/having.php).

```
   Select title
   From books
   Group By name
   Having retail> avg(retail)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM books
  WHERE price >= (SELECT avg(price) FROM books);
```